# QGIS calculate coverage density

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have a survey line plan (a grid of lines along which to acquire data - dark lines in picture).
Each line images data out to either 150m or 300m from the centre line. I have visualised this by making the 'Simple Line' width the appropriate width based on a column in my data.
Is is possible to calculate the density of coverage from this? What I want to know is how many times an area is imaged, e.g. 1 pass = only seen once = 100%, 2 passes = seen from 2 passes = 200%, etc.
The lines radiating out will only have 1 pass where they extend beyond the main grid, but may have 500% where they near the site centre.
I don't know if any of the 'line density' options would work as I'm not looking at real data (beyond the line itself), I'm looking at a width projection of the line.
Would I have to create a Polygon of each line?
[image]

Using Erik's Answer below, I now have categorised coverage density - This is a mini test example for clarity.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to your centerlines, then buffer them so the polygons will be as wide as your swaths. Then run the SAGA tool `polygonselfintersection` on the buffers. No need to provide a key field.

[image]

You can now count the number of pipes in the new field `ID` and add 1 in order to determine how many times an area will be covered by your survey. Which actually is not as trivial as I thought it was, sorry.

Comment: How do I buffer the lines?

Comment: Are you asking how the [buffer tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=buffer#buffer) works?

Comment: Perfect. I now have the buffer 'polygons' and can categorize based on ID. Edited question with results and marked as Answer